# How to fix raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr) when importing excel that includes one of the fields is empty

Tags: python-dateutil

datefield error when null with django openpyxl

I want to import excel sheet but ones date fields are empty.

```
class Drgmt(models.Model):
      date_ori = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True, blank=True)


def import(request):
    #Many lines before
    date_ori = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[19]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #Many lines after
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", l
ine 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 1
15, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 1
13, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\performance\cuivre\views.py", line 57, in importeradsl date_ori = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[19]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", li
ne 1356, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", li
ne 648, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', 'None')
[18/Jun/2019 08:37:02] "POST /cuivre/ HTTP/1.1" 500 85133
```

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example and the full traceback.

Comment: I add full traceback

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with Django actually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is rather clear: you're passing the string `'None'` as the `timestr` argument of `dateutil.parser.parse()`, and the parser can't parse this to a date obviously.

The solution is obvious too: [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

```
def import(request):
    #Many lines before
    try:
        date_ori = parse(row_data[19])
    except ValueError as e:
        # what you want to do here depends on your app's specs and rules...
        # you could return an error response, or skip the row and
        # just display a warning, etc etc
        do_something_with_the_exception_here()
    else:
        date_ori = dt.datetime.strftime(date_ori, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    #Many lines after
```